# In EF (Entity Framework) what stategy to change field type between INT and SMALLINT in multiply aplication?

Tags: entity-framework

I have two or more application and can`t update in one time

I want use type INT in model in one new application with field "Serial" with type SMALLINT in db and it must work when type in DB will changed to INT in feature without exception in new code

For old applications

```
public class Machine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public short Serial { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

For new applications

```
public class Machine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Serial { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Here where can be exeption

```
var machine = context.Machines.FirstOrDefault(o => o.id == id);
```

When i use Stored Procedures it type indepeded, i what do same

```
 var serial = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataReader["Serial"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add view in database with cast to SMALLINT or INT if you want to increase or decrease maximum value for choosed field

Sample:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[view_machines]
AS
SELECT id, CAST(serial AS INT) AS serial
FROM     dbo.machines
```

now you can change in table machines field type to INT or SMALLINT anytime